# What's the name for a function where each output has one input but there could be invalid inputs?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

An example of this is the function f(x) = 1/x, where x is an element of the rational numbers. Each output corresponds to only one input, but for x = 0, there is no output.

I'm mostly asking because I just learned the terms injective, surjective, and bijective, and this is the inverse of an injective function.

I know that this is technically not a function, but am still curious as to what the name for it is.

Comment: What do you mean by 'invalid inputs'? Any such 'input' is not in the domain of the function. And if by 'one input', you mean *exactly* one preimage, then it's a bijection.

Comment: As an example, say you have the input set {0,2}, which, after operating on it, produces {5} as the ouput set. The 5 is a result of the input 2, and the input 0 produced nothing. What would you call this aside from "not a function"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be called a *partial function*.  See wikipedia: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)

Comment: +1. Specifically, I think the OP is talking about *injective partial functions.*

Comment: @Noah Schweber: This is exactly it. Thanks!